# Перенести нейросеть bratgpt в discord

Tags: python, html, json, requests, discord

Я пытаюсь с помощью языка python и библиотеки requests перенести нейросеть bratgpt в discord. Делаю своего бота на python и решил добавить команду bad, при выполнении которой будет включаться нейросеть bratgpt. Я понял, как обрабатывать информацию с сайта, и в итоге у меня в данный момент в терминале пишет только текст написанный на сайте, но ответа на моё сообщение "привет" нету. Я не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал на моё сообщение. Прошу подсказать
Код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def bad(ctx):
    data = {'message':"hi"}
    response = rq.get(
    url = 'https://bratgpt.com/',params=data)
    print("Ваш статус - ",response)
    f = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f,features="html5lib")
    data = {}
    data['title'] = soup.title.text
    data['body'] = soup.body.text
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    k = json.loads(json_data)
    print(k)
    print('всё')
```

Я не очень хорошо знаю python, в частности библиотеку requests, поэтому, возможно, я допустил какую-нибудь глупую ошибку